# D3.js Plotting Multiple Data Sets from Separate Files

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a scatter plot with two sets of data from two tsv files. However, each one shares the x-axis with single scale. There are two y-axis each with their own scale. [image: The graph] The graph I have right now will help visually.

Problem is, the 2nd data set (in orange) only plots partially as seen as a smudge at about 15,000 on the a-axis. it should really be a much larger line. Also, when I run this, sometimes the 2nd data set renders and the first does now. Not sure why this is happening..

Here are the two (likely) relevant blocks of code:

```
    //1st data set
    d3.tsv("datatest4.tsv", function(error, tsv1) {

        tsv1.forEach(function(d) {
            d.altit = +d.altit;
            d.tmp = +d.tmp;

        });

        x.domain(d3.extent(tsv1, function(d) { return d.altit; })).nice();
        y.domain(d3.extent(tsv1, function(d) { return d.tmp; })).nice();

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("x", width)
            .attr("y", -6)
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Altitude (m)");

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis axis1")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end");

        svg.selectAll(".dot")
            .data(tsv1)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "dot")
            .attr("r", 1)
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.altit); })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.tmp); })
            .style("fill","steelblue");

    });
```

and

```
    //2nd data set
    d3.tsv("datatest2.tsv", function(error, tsv2) {

        tsv2.forEach(function(dd) {
            dd.alti = +dd.alti;
            dd.pressure = +dd.pressure;
        });

        x2.domain(d3.extent(tsv2, function(dd) { return dd.alti; })).nice();
        y2.domain(d3.extent(tsv2, function(dd) { return dd.pressure; })).nice();

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis2)
            .attr("x", width)
            .attr("y", -6)
            .text("Altitude (m)");

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis axis2")
            .call(yAxis2)
            .append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end");

        svg.selectAll(".dot")
            .data(tsv2)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "dot")
            .attr("r", 1)
            .attr("cx", function(dd) { return x2(dd.alti); })
            .attr("cy", function(dd) { return y2(dd.pressure); })
            .style("fill","orange");    

    });
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same selector, `svg.selectAll(".dot")`, for each dataset `.data(tsv1)` and `.data(tsv2)`.

D3 thinks that the 2nd set is supposed to replace the first. You can fix it by assigning a unique class to each type of dot.

```
    svg.selectAll(".blue.dot")// Select specifically blue dots
        .data(tsv1)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "blue dot")// Assign two classes
        ...

    svg.selectAll(".orange.dot")
        .data(tsv2)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "orange dot")
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks - totally noob move. I thought .dot was something defined by d3. Live and learn.

Comment: :) Thank's countfloortiles and@Sumod for your vote of confidence, but it appears that @ToddSherman hasn't been back on this site roughly since the day he posted this question. I think we lost him :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay :)