# D3: Drawing 3 csv in 1 graph with a function for each, but 2 don't work

Tags: javascript, function, csv, d3.js

I am trying to create a basic but working interactive MCA (for multiple correspondence analysis) with D3.
One of my function works perfectly (the Indiv one), but the 2 others, although formatted in the same way, don't.

```
var margin = {right: 30, left: 30, top: 50, bottom: 50},
    width = 620 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500+margin.top + margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-2,3])
    .range([0,width])

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([2,-2])
    .range([0,height]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")  
    .tickSize(1);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickSize(1);

var canvas = d3.select(".result-side1")
    .append("svg") 
    .attr("width", width+20) 
    .attr("height", height+20)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(30,30)');

canvas.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height-30) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
canvas.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

canvas.append("text") 
    .attr("x", (width / 2)) 
    .attr("y", 40 - (margin.top)) 
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle") 
    .style("font-size", "22px") 
    .style("text-decoration", "underline") 
    .attr("fill","white")
    .text("Les Etats classés selon leur profil");


function affichInd(){
var individus = canvas.append("g");
d3.csv("donnees/USAindiv.csv", function(error, data)
{
 //Add data to the graph and call enter.
 var dataEnter = individus.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter();
 var dataEntertext = individus.selectAll("text").data(data).enter();
 dataEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d,i){return x(d.Dim1);})
    .attr("cy", function(d,i){return y(d.Dim2);})
    .attr("r", 2)
    .attr("fill","#3399FF");
dataEntertext.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d,i){return x(d.Dim1);})
    .attr("y", function(d,i){return y(d.Dim2);})
    .attr("fill","#3399FF")
    .text(function(d,i){return d.State});
    })
 }
/* These last two don't work */

/*Variables*/   
function affichVar(){
var variables = canvas.append("g");
d3.csv("donnees/USAvaria.csv",
function(error, datavaria)
{
 //Add data to the graph and call enter.
 var datavariaEnter = variables.selectAll("circle").data(datavaria).enter();
 var datavariaEntertext = variables.selectAll("text").data(datavaria).enter();
 datavariaEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d,i){return x(d.Dim1);})
    .attr("cy", function(d,i){return y(d.Dim2);})
    .attr("r", 2)
    .attr("fill","#B9CC14");
datavariaEntertext.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d,i){return x(d.Dim1);})
    .attr("y", function(d,i){return y(d.Dim2);})
    .attr("fill","#B9CC14")
    .text(function(d,i){return d.Variables});
})
}

/*Variables supplémentaires*/
function affichVarSupp(){
var variablessupp = canvas.append("g");
d3.csv("donnees/USAvasup.csv", function(error, datavasup)
{
 //Add data to the graph and call enter.
 var datavasupEnter = variablessupp.selectAll("circle").data(datavasup).enter();
 var datavasupEntertext = variablessupp.selectAll("text").data(datavasup).enter();
 datavasupEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d,i){return x(d["Dim1"]);})
    .attr("cy", function(d,i){return y(d["Dim2"]);})
    .attr("r", 2)
    .attr("fill","#FF584C");
datavasupEntertext.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d,i){return x(d["Dim1"]);})
    .attr("y", function(d,i){return y(d["Dim2"]);})
    .attr("fill","#FF584C")
    .text(function(d,i){return d.Qualisup});

})
}
```

Is there any reason why this would not work?

I have tried fiddling with bits of code, that's why they are not all exactly similar, but I think I missed something conceptual...
Here is what I get : http://www.victoralexandre.fr/d3_acm_3.html

Thanks for your help !
Vic.

Comment: It's the same as the issue [addressed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715900/d3-js-plotting-multiple-data-sets-from-separate-files/13717110#13717110).

Comment: Hi @meetamit, thanks so much for your explanation. It's clear that was some kind of classic mistake. However, it still does not work now that I've made the changes. (you can check the same web page quoted up there)...

Comment: Not sure. There's too much going on there. The console is complaining about `cx=NaN` (and `cy`, `x`, `y`). So `d.Dim1` is null. You have to check if your data is parsed properly. And also insert `console.log` in a place where you're returning `d.Dim1`, so that you can check it. Etc.

Comment: Cheers. I'm going to console log everything and tell here what was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer my friends, was blowing in the file: I just had to change the d3.csv to a d3.tsv and the NaN became numbers.

Hurray. (although it's not quite clear to me why that happened)

Comment: It happened because your CSV is not actually Comma-Separated-Values. Instead, your values are Tab-Separated-Values, and using d3.tsv tells the parser to look for tabs -- not commas -- in the file when it parses the data.