# How to enter data from several variables into one chart using d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

It is quite easy to enter data in d3 as long as all of the data are in one file or in one variable like this:

```
svg.selectAll("path").data(datavariable).enter()
    .append("path")
    ....
```

I need to enter data stored in separate variables into one graph. I tried

```
svg.selectAll("path").data(datavariable1).enter()
    .append("path")
    ....
 svg.selectAll("path").data(datavariable2).enter()
    .append("path")
    ....
```

It doesn't seem to work. I also tried `svg.selectAll("path1")...` and `svg.selectAll("path.datavariable1")...`, but it just plots the second path over the first using the same data (`datavariable1`). Does anyone know how to get data from two variables to work on one graph at the same time?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715900/d3-js-plotting-multiple-data-sets-from-separate-files ?

Comment: how about like this using `merge`
`svg.selectAll("path").data(d3.merge(datavariable1, datavraiable2)).enter()
    .append("path") ...`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of Nixie's comment. This is what worked for me. For the paths I didn't need to `svg.selectAll` anything. `line1` and `line2` get the data from data variables:

```
var line1 = d3.line()
    .x(function(d,i) { return x(datavariable1[i].xvalue); })
    .y(function(d,i) { return y(datavariable1[i].yvalue); });

var line2 = d3.line()
    .x(function(d,i) { return x(datavariable2[i].xvalue); })
    .y(function(d,i) { return y(datavariable2[i].yvalue); });
```

Then I just appended SVG as follows:

```
svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line1(datavariable1))


svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line2(datavariable2))
```

Answer in Nixie's comment to my question wouldn't work in my case because `path` has to stay `path` for the line graph, but it works for a dot graph. Hopefully this helps someone who might run into similar issue.